# Align Scrollbar to left of the Silverlight ListBox

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

The below is an image of a listbox with the listbox items present in it :
I want the scrollbar of a listbox to be aligned on left side

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/231f3112d3.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/231f3112d3.png)

**Edit After Hans answered :**
I tried what Hans said in my previous code was :

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"  FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Column="0"  />
                    </Grid>
```

But as my ItemsPresenter  was a child of ScrollViewer, so its FlowDirection property also get changed to  RightToLeft which i din't want.So to resolve this I just gaved value LeftToRight to its property.

**New Edit :**

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"  FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Column="0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the FlowDirection property to RightToLeft.